# saveAsTextFile performance improvement

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I have used the datasource with the following format upto 1500000

```
1
2
3
4
5
..
1500000
```

I have use the following code snippet

```
JavaRDD<String> dataCollection=ctx.textFile("hdfs://yarncluster/Input/datasource");

JavaPairRDD<String,String> rdd=dataCollection.cartesian(dataCollection);

rdd.saveAsTextFile("hdfs://yarncluster/Ouput");
```

It take more time to save the data in cluster. 
Is there any other way to improve the performance?

Comment: Your result dataset is huge.

Comment: yes, is there any other default option for parallize the saveAsTextFile operations

Answer (score 1):

You could increase the level of parallelism by calling repartition with a large number of partitions.